# Gradle: Fetch transitive dependencies and export to minimal runtime fat jar

Tags: groovy, build, jar, gradle, proguard

How can I ensure that Gradle fetches all declared and transitive dependencies and adds them to the output jar? I'm trying to use the recipe outlined [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GRADLE/Cookbook#Cookbook-Includeallruntimedependencies), but it appears not to actually be including transitive dependencies.

I would like to have these dependencies included so that ProGuard can optimize and shrink the output properly.

Here's an example `build.gradle` that shows that transitive dependencies aren't being pulled:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile('com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.4.3') { transitive = true }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:4.10'
    }
}

jar {
    dependsOn configurations.runtime
    from { 
        configurations.runtime.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
}

task proguard(type: proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask, dependsOn: build) {
    configurations.runtime.each {
        println it
    }
    injars jar.archivePath
    outjars 'output.jar'
    libraryjars "${System.getProperty('java.home')}/lib/rt.jar"

    keep "public class part1.** { * ; }"

    //dontnote
    //dontwarn
    dontobfuscate
}
```

For this sample project I'm using the code sample from http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=12. The [POM at MavenCentral](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.itextpdf%7Citextpdf%7C5.4.3%7Cjar) indicates the BouncyCastle libraries as compile dependencies, yet the above `build.gradle` does not package them into the output JAR or even pull them into the `~/.gradle` artifact cache.

The result is that when I run `gradle proguard` with warnings enabled, the build fails due to `org.bouncycastle.*` classes not being resolved. For example:

```
Warning: com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.TSAClientBouncyCastle: can't find referenced class org.bouncycastle.tsp.TimeStampTokenInfo
```

If it is not possible to resolve this issue with ProGuard (disabling warnings works here, but not in my larger project, again due to similar error messages), is there another way to have Gradle shrink a full-runtime fat-jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at `itextpdf`'s POM, all its dependencies are either test dependencies or optional. Hence, unless you declare further dependencies, only `itextpdf` itself will be included in your fat Jar.